# Composite key configuration in EF6 code first model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, one-to-one

I have 3 tables, 2 tables are the principal ones and 3rd is the dependent table, following is the structure.

```
public class Class1
{
     public int Id;
     public string Name;

     public Class3 Class3Property;
}

public class Class2
{
     public int Id;
     public string Name;

     public Class3 Class3Property;
}

public class Class3
{
     [Key, ForeignKey("Class1Property"), Column(Order = 1)]
     public int Class1Id;
     [Key, ForeignKey("Class2Property"), Column(Order = 2)]
     public int Class2Id;

     public Class1 Class1Property;
     public Class2 Class2Property;
}
```

It works, but it creates additional properties in Class3

1. Class1_Id
2. Class2_Id

How to avoid these additional fields getting added.

Comment: Do you really intend `Class1` and `Class3` to have a 1:1 relationship? (and  `Class2` and `Class3`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess  that since you have 3 tables , you are trying to make many-to-many relations. So you need to fix some relations

```
public class Class1
{
     public int Id;
     public string Name;

     public Virtual ICollection <Class3> Class3Properties;
}

public class Class2
{
     public int Id;
     public string Name;

     public vitural ICollection<Class3> Class3Properties;
}

public class Class3
{
     [Key,  Column(Order = 1)]
     public int Class1Id;
     [Key,, Column(Order = 2)]
     public int Class2Id;

     [ForeignKey("Class1Id")],
     public Class1 Class1;
      [ForeignKey("Class2Id")]
     public Class2 Class2;
}
```

you don't need the third table for one to one , would be enough 2 tables, if you are using old ef6 your code could be

```
public class Class1
{    
     [Key]
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     
    [Index( "INDEX_Class2", IsClustered=false, IsUnique=true )]   
     public int Class2Id {get; set;}

     ForeignKey(nameof(Class2Id))]
    [InverseProperty("Class1")]
     public virtual  Class2 Class2 {get; set;}
    
}

public class Class2
{
      [Key]
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     [InverseProperty("Class2")]
     public vitural ICollection<Class1> Class1 {get; set;};
}
```

Comment: This is about EF6, which without further notice should be understood as the old EF6. Also, if you would have tested the code you'd have noticed something's wrong.

Comment: @GertArnold  Thank you for advice,  It was just a hint. I added some attributes if you think it is needed.